# A problem on normal distribution to calculate the probability

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

A sample of size 10 is drawn from a normal population with mean and variance both equal to y(>0) and the first quartile is 2.65.
Find the probability that

a) the first four observations are negative.

b) four observations are negative.

For this problem, I have been trying to find out the corresponding Z score and all but am still not on track.
Kindly help someone to lead me the way for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

It can be found by numerical methods that $y=4$, with $X\sim \mathscr N(4, 4)$ giving $Pr(X\le 2.65)\approx.25$.

Assuming independently drawn observations, For a, the probability is $Pr(X<0)^4Pr(X\ge0)^6$

For b, the probability is ${10 \choose 4}$ times the quantity from part a.

Answer (score 1):

> It can be found by numerical methods that y=4

It can easily be found exactly solving the following biquadratic equation

$$\frac{2.65-y}{\sqrt{y}}=-0.675$$

That is like

$$t^2-0.675t-2.65=0$$

Which gives $t=\sqrt{y}=2$

Comment: hmm interesting